# How to change an href attribute through Javascript on a modal window

Tags: javascript

I've been searching and trying different ways to change an href attribute through Javascript. Few things have worked better than others.

The problem with this approach is that the variable on the href is not working. I guess there is a better way to include a variable within an html tag.

I'm really stuck on this so would appreciate any help.

Here is the code of the modal window:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="modal-close">&times;</span>
<h1>¿Quieres seguir creando?</h1>
<a class="btn-ok" href=enlace target="_blank">OK</a>
</div>
</div>
```

And this the button that the user clicks on before the modal window is shown:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var enlace;
</script> 
<button onclick="enlace='https://cloqq.com/actividad/tu-aventura-interactiva';return false" id="" class="go-btn pink-bg">Empieza a crear
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute

You can use setAttribute to reassign the href, the way you're using javascript in html doesnt work like that.

```js
const itemYouWantToUpdateHref = document.querySelector('.btn-ok')


function changeHref(link) {
  itemYouWantToUpdateHref.setAttribute('href', link);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-ok" href="www.google.com" target="_blank">My link will change</a>
<button onclick="changeHref('www.youtube.com')">click to change href from google to youtube</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code itself with only some changes and without any `script tag`. look at code below:

```html
<button onclick="window.enlace='https://cloqq.com/actividad/tu-aventura-interactiva'" class="go-btn pink-bg">Empieza a crear</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
<span class="modal-close">&times;</span>
<h1>¿Quieres seguir creando?</h1>
<a class="btn-ok" href="javascript:window.open(window.enlace||'defaultAddress', '_blank');">OK</a>
<!--
   !! If you like to show an alert when the button is not clicked yet, try line below instead above line:
   <a class="btn-ok" href="javascript:window.enlace?window.open(window.enlace, '_blank'):alert('Please click the Button first!');">OK</a>
-->
</div>
</div>
```

**If** you run above snippet and look at console, you can see **all things is fine** (but because Security problems this will not work with these `URL`s in current page and you should copy it in your project or an empty html file for seeing the result.)

Comment: attaching it to window doesnt seem like the best idea just incase he overwrites the varible in one of his scripts, but fair enough good solution

Comment: what was interesting for me, was using his code itself and correcting it :). but one way which can be helpful in that case, is attaching it to the button itself like this: `this.enlace='our_address'`. now in `ok` link, instead of `window.enlace`: `document.querySelector('.go-btn.pink-bg').enlace` or other similar assign ways :)